# Dynamic load ngModule forRoot object inside app_initializer

Tags: javascript, angular, reload

Actually I have external library imported in ngModule inside app.module and am passing dynamic value as link to external module but problem is its not updating new values with library -

```
MyExternalModule.forRoot({
            link: "https://www.google.com/", // dynamic value, this might change once get response from app_initializer
        }),
```

And i want use updated link value and am getting same `link: "https://www.google.com/"` value all over the application, so Basically i want to update `MyExternalModule` library with new values which is am passing